# Saving filtered features to separate shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am using "Export - Save as" of layers filtered features, from a Temporary file, to get a new layer which holds only filtered features.

It goes well considering features I get. But I see some of the Fieldnames only hold a part of original name.

Can I prevent this and get a full name?

Answer (score 8):

You can keep the full names by not using Shapefiles.

Shapefiles are limited to a length of max. 10 characters as fieldnames. There is no way around shortening the names except for using another format, such as Geopackage for example.

Also see these articles by ESRI:

- https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/shapefiles/adding-a-field-in-a-shapefile-in-arccatalog.htm
- https://www.esri.com/content/dam/esrisites/sitecore-archive/Files/Pdfs/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf

Answer (score 7):

Don't export to ShapeFile, use GeoPackage (or another more modern file format).

ShapeFile field names can only be 10 characters long (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00126-00150-000142.htm).